# Unable to connect to Rancher UI on browser after creating its Container on my host machine

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers, port, rancher

**TL;DR: After creating the container, I can't access the web UI from my IP.**

I am currently following the [official rancher document](https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/v2.5/getting-started/quick-start-guides/deploy-rancher-manager/helm-cli) for manually setting up Rancher on my host machine.

It was asked in the document to let the Rancher container have Port 80 & 443 for listening requests. However, since I already had these Ports set on something else on my system, I changed the ports and ran this command:

```
sudo docker run --privileged -d --restart=unless-stopped -p 8312:80 -p 4312:443 rancher/rancher
```

What I was expecting was that I would be able to open the Rancher UI from browser using the "https://192.168.43.166:4312" or "https://192.168.43.166:8132" URL but I am unable to do so as I am shown the "This site can’t be reached" error on my browser.

Please note that all of this is happening on my host machine. While all the tutorials for setting up container are being done in VMs, I kind of went against them and tried to set it up on my base machine. If this is a wrong approach, please tell me and I will also set up Rancher by creating containers inside VMs...